# Replace characters in filenames with new characters

Tags: batch-file, replace, filenames

I am trying to batch rename files to replace hard brackets [] in filename with soft brackets ().

All files have the form series[sxxexx]title.mp4

Plex will not load files with [] so I need to replace;

```
*[*]*.mp4 with *(*)*.mp4
```

Searching for something to use has led to:

```
@echo on
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=*[*]*"
Set "Replace=*(*)*"

For %%a in (*.mp4) Do (
Set "File=%%a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

pause&Exit
```

Or maybe something like

```
@echo on
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "PL=["
Set "PR=]"
Set "RL=("
Set "RR=)"

For %%a in (*.mp4) Do (
    Set "File=%%a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%PL%PR%=%RL%RR%!"
)

 pause&Exit
```

Others have said something like this worked for them but it does nothing for me. So I don't know how to adjust it to make it work.

Comment: that can't work. you need to use two replacements: `set "file=%%~a`, `set "file=!file:[=(!"`, `set "file:]=)!"`. Your Patterns are fine for filenames (`for %%a in (%pattern%) do...` would work fine), but not for replacement.

Comment: FYI, if you're willing to give Powershell a try you can do that in one line, so either in a script or at the Powershell prompt using this :
`Get-ChildItem *.mp3 | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("[","(").Replace("]",")")}`

Comment: Did you not mean to use ```%PL%%PR%=%RL%%RR%``` instead of ```%PL%PR%=%RL%RR%``` in your recent [Edit].

Comment: I get what your saying about doing two renames I was sorta thinking the same with the 2 variable thing. so then I would need 2 rename commands in the DO ? I tried it as stephan wrote and got nothing.

Compo I think the others were just replacing 1 word and I thought I could adjust it like so but no go

Keith this is the simplest solution I prefer to go folder by folder cause some I dont want to mess with. just open terminal paste the line and done thank you. 

I knew this was a simple fix just couldn't get how to write it. 

Compo I tried an extra % sign not sure why but it did nothing

Comment: There is absolutely no need to do it in a single rename, and @Stephan already explained that you couldn't do it like that, using your methodology. Also, as a supplement to my last comment, you do realise that your filenames do not have the sequence `[]` anywhere in them, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=[]" %%u IN ('dir /b/a-d "%sourcedir%\*[*]*.mp4" 2^>nul') DO  ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%u[%%v]%%w" "%%u(%%v)%%w"
dir/s /on "u:\your files"


GOTO :EOF
```

Remove the `echo` keyword after verification to actually perform the rename operation